# Which CVE notice applies?

Tags: updates, security

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm finding the notices related to CVEs to be confusing.  For example, when I look at a specific CVE detailed at https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2019/CVE-2019-14901.html I see that page references several others, including:

1. https://usn.ubuntu.com/4227-1/
2. https://usn.ubuntu.com/4228-1/

I am running a 16.04 LTS server, and those two references indicate they are related to 16.04 LTS.  But what confuses me is that they give different information regarding how the problem can be corrected. #1 specifies upgrading to 4.15.0 versions, while #2 specifies upgrading to 4.4.0 versions.  Why is the "corrected" version for 16.04 LTS different on these two pages, and which is really the correct information?

And on top of that, the original CVE URL says the flaw was found "in the Linux kernel, all versions 3.x.x and 4.x.x before 4.18.0."  Huh?  So why does it tell me to update to either 4.4.0 or 4.15.0 when both of those are less than 4.18?

Comment: Because you don't need to run kernel version 4.15, 4.18 or 5.3 in your distribution.  Those kernel versions are actually ones that come with newer versions of Ubuntu.  The 4.4 kernel version originally came with 16.04 LTS and if you didn't do the HWE upgrade you would still be using the 4.4 kernel and it is still fully supported, hence the updates to the existing kernel instead of forcing you to upgrade to 4.15.  See:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  If you change to HWE you tend to get the newer kernels around the point releases of the LTS distro.

Comment: So really, the source of my confusion is that the 2 notices assume people will already understand the GA versus HWE distinction.  Maybe that is a safe assumption, but a newbie like me wasn't aware of it.  So maybe it is just unclear communication.  It seems these articles ought to condition their statements that "The problem can be corrected by updating your system to the following package versions" to distinguish things.  Otherwise, for people unfamiliar with all this--and some security scanning tools--they may simply and incorrectly say you're less than 4.15.x, so you are vulnerable.

Comment: You might also want to look into the [Canonical Livepatch Service](https://ubuntu.com/livepatch).  It's free to end users and can patch your kernel on the fly as long as you are using a supported distro at the time and it has not gone EOL and is a LTS release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may be confused between the 4.4 (normal, or GA) and 4.15 (HWE) kernels, which is a fairly ordinary confusion. Review https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack for more clarity. Both normal and HWE kernel versions are patched--and both are 16.04 LTS kernels.

Advice to upgrade to a different kernel version is generally for folks who are not using Ubuntu. The Ubuntu Security Team generally patches most packages (including the kernel), without bumping the version. The patched kernel is just as safe as the new version.

To learn more about how the [Ubuntu Security Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam) handles cases like these, check out the [Ubuntu Security Podcast](https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/).

Comment: So if I want to address CVE-2019-14901, and if I am using the "GA" 16.04, then I can expect my kernel will be updated to a linux-image-4.4.0-171-generic version, correct?  If I was running a HWE version, I would expect to be updated to a 4.15 version.    I'm not clear on how I would know if I am using a "GA" or a "HWE" version (I didn't originally set up this server).  I have this package installed which is subject to this CVE: linux-image-4.13.0-37-generic.

Comment: I believe 4.15 is the running kernel, but older kernels are likely present on the system and getting flagged by security scanners as vulnerable--even though I'm not running them, they are flagged because they are present.  I've already followed the upgrade steps so I don't believe I have any lingering vulnerability, but I asked this question so I can fully understand and clear up my confusion on these notices.  Sorry, I should have made that clear.

Comment: How to be sure exactly what kernel version you are running: The command `uname`